# Script in spreadsheet to save sheet as csv and upload to cloud storage

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I have a script that everyday gets data from Google analytics and then I delete the sheet, so next day I can download it again.

What I need is to save that sheet as .csv and upload it to a cloud storage everyday, any ideas about how can I do that ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could do that; but wouldn't it be simpler just to download it (or rename it) to a filename which includes the date, so that you don't have to delete it each time?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't want to have sheets for everyday in the spreadsheet, I onlye need them in cloud storage. Anyway, do you know if there is any way to upload .csv or .tsv from spreadsheet script to cloud storage? Thanks for your time

Comment: I've never used Google Cloud Storage, but I found out more by clicking on the [tag:google-cloud-storage] tag on your question. Their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) has a QuickStart guide that shows exactly how to upload a file, using the `gsutil` command line utility. (The type of file should not matter.)

Answer (score 3):

To download your file as csv you can make use of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets), which basically consists on using the following:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{DOCID}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}
```

Replacing {DOCID} with your Document ID and {sheet_name} with the name of the sheet. If you only have one sheet, there is a more straightforward way:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{DOCID}/export?format=csv
```

As already mentioned by @jpaugh, to upload the file to cloud storage you can use the official docs, specifically [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#upload): Where it is explained how to upload an object to a bucket using  any of the available options,
 which are:

1. Using the Console
2. Using `gsutil` command
3. Using any of the client libraries: C#,GO,Java,Node.js, PHP, Python or Ruby
4. Using any of the REST APIS (JSON or XML).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get any simpler than using `Pandas`:

```
def build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_id):
    return f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{doc_id}/export?format=csv&gid={sheet_id}'

def write_df_to_gs(df, gs_key):
    df.to_csv(gs_key)

doc_id = 'DOC_ID'
sheet_id = 'SHEET_ID'
sheet_url = build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_id)
df = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)
gs_key = 'GS_KEY'
write_df_to_gs(df, gs_key)
```