# How do I download a google spreadsheet as csv?

Tags: linux, csv, google-sheets, wget, export-to-csv

Hi I am using wget to extract google spreadsheet as csv

I used the following command

wget "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_HERE/export?=csv"

but I am getting the HTML output

I have already used the google sheets api to extract data row by row and convert to csv but its very slow need a faster method

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use google sheets api if you want to get the csv output of google spreadsheet

Comment: I have already used the google sheets api to extract data row by row and convert to csv but its very slow need a faster method

Comment: one api call to google spreadsheet api will given you all the rows so after getting the response just convert it to csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets)

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the following post

[Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets)

> To download a specific sheet as a CSV file, replace {key} with the document's ID and {sheet_name} with the name of the sheet to export:
>
> ```
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}
> ```

Note: Copied from the above post. Thanks @kiwidrew (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390231/kiwidrew)