# How to retrieve JSON object from google sheets and not HTML

Tags: node.js, json, rest, api, google-sheets

I m sending a GET request to a published google sheets. All the tutorials show that a JSON object is returned but I receive HTML. Is it due to an update? How can I parse it into JSON?

Published sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTLSQ-WGM8O0iCCTal0eFoAvFFIVK04UxUiCuBJLGVy89EY301-0cF5PZupIXh-sF_L9pHIw6tVtN1G/pubhtml

Expected output when you go to the link: JSON object

Obtained output: HTML

References:
https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/general/databasing-google-spreadsheets-to-json

https://medium.com/storyline-blog/how-to-create-a-dynamic-alexa-skill-using-google-sheets-and-storyline-9fd37f2080d8

In these, JSON is returned when a request is made whereas I receive an HTML

An example of google sheet returning JSON:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEET_ID/od6/public/basic?alt=json

Comment: Which tutorial? You'd  probably need to add a url query  parameter

Comment: I added them in the question now @TheMaster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets)

Comment: Nope. I get a page not found error if I use the same URL template

Comment: Does out:csv work?

Comment: It does not change anything @TheMaster

Comment: You're doing  something wrong.  Here's a working sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14kqcSOMBEIdnnmX6rdMpIVMH9w3KUCWzMgB9s3tTD3I/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json for the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14kqcSOMBEIdnnmX6rdMpIVMH9w3KUCWzMgB9s3tTD3I/edit

Comment: @TheMaster When i publish a spreadhseet, i get the following url:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQdsaEdzg1DzH27fzs5c0a8jv3h5T2Q5TmIYAsPeRoCpKiIuF4H0cQjrbPj1lbdb302WIHiMkAJN0tS/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true 

whereas you get : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14kqcSOMBEIdnnmX6rdMpIVMH9w3KUCWzMgB9s3tTD3I/edit . Any idea why?

Comment: You should use the unpublished link.

Comment: Thanks. I got the JSON but it is now asking me for Oauth credential

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Thank you

Comment: Hello @SumanthSomshekhar, could you post the complete solution as an answer?So others running into the same issue can solve it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish a google sheet, you are prompted by a pop displaying a link such as

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTVZ3fWRSMu5nFGUc05ACV1h0-UGW49wi9lHAyJVUMp8FX3TANqy_9WNhkcd4z1mJSSN-LZyyBdS_vK/pubhtml

2PACX-1vTVZ3fWRSMu5nFGUc05ACV1h0-UGW49wi9lHAyJVUMp8FX3TANqy_9WNhkcd4z1mJSSN-LZyyBdS_vK **is not the skill id**

**The skill ID is present in the search bar.** For example the search bar has the link, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bm6Fjiacmuh0qRjuHoBU35AHPdF7S4R7BEIK46H0wUo/edit#gid=0

where **1bm6Fjiacmuh0qRjuHoBU35AHPdF7S4R7BEIK46H0wUo is the link.**