# Google Sheets JSON feeed - I want the data not the schema

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Postman, with calls such as GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XJgmvAGNmpyJieZTh40PuoKHoKOI1CJlMqSStu75fWo/od6/public/basic?alt=json&range=(A1:F101).getValue()

I get a JSON feed with xml schema, eg
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
    "feed": {
        "xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
        "xmlns$openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/",
        "xmlns$gsx": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended",
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XJgmvAGNmpyJieZTh40PuoKHoKOI1CJlMqSStu75fWo/od6/public/basic"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2020-02-27T00:58:42.663Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list".

**I only want the data in the sheet.**

What inline script do I use to get a range of data eg A1:C6

OR all data (only)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

### Question

How to get data values from Spreadsheet with GET request?

### Answer

Use this format:

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**SPREADSHEET_ID**/values/**RANGE**?majorDimension=COLUMNS&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**

So finally it should look like this:

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**1XJgmvAGNmpyJieZTh40PuoKHoKOI1CJlMqSStu75fWo**/values/**A1:F101**?majorDimension=COLUMNS&key=**[YOUR_API_KEY]**

Try [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?apix=true) so you can adapt it to your needs

The response is:

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:C21",
  "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
  "values": [
    [
      "a1",
      "a2",
...
      "c19",
      "c20",
      "c21"
    ]
  ]
}
```

And now it is time to format it with `forEach` or whatever you like.