# What is the direct download link for Google Sheets HTML export?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a google apps script that would export a Google Sheet as an HTML file and place it in my Google Drive, however I need a direct download link in my script, and I couldn't find a working URL for exporting a spreadsheet as HTML. In addition to the data the HTML should also include any images embedded in the spreadsheet.

The direct download link for my Google sheet appears to work when exporting PDF as follows:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TavkbXHhw3hrDaRKhhNsevyRCM_UG8VD0x-d5eZnHZE/export?format=pdf

however, when swapping out 'format=pdf' to 'format=html' I get an error.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TavkbXHhw3hrDaRKhhNsevyRCM_UG8VD0x-d5eZnHZE/export?format=html

and the problem appears to be just for html, since the links for .csv, .xlsx, and .ods also work fine.

This solution comes close, but it downloads a .zip that has the html file inside it https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184071/19982878

It should be noted that Google *Docs* has a direct download link for HTML, which is showcased in this video (at 5:31) https://youtu.be/Rwau69hCC4Y?list=LL&t=331
Swapping out the ID for mine and 'document' to 'spreadsheet' didn't work in this case either.