# How to export Google Sheets as CSV using the gviz URL, including collapsed group rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

As seen here [Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets/33727897#33727897) it's possible to download a Google Sheet using an URL.

In my sheet I have some rows grouped, and it's properly exported if they're expanded. However, if I minimize a group and then try to download it using the link, the contents of the minimized groups are omitted.

Is it possible to also include the minimized groups without having to manually expand every group?