# Downloading Google sheet using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, python-requests, download

I am trying to download google sheet using belowcode. However it is not giving unexpected result by printing differennt characters into xls sheet. Any idea what could be wrong. Code:

```
url = 'google_docs_link'
user, password = 'user', 'pwd'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password))
print(resp)
with open('C:\\AAA\\exportdata.xls', "wb") as o:
    o.write(resp.content)`
```

```
print(resp) is giving the output of <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download link for Google Spreadsheets CSV export - with Multiple Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am not sure if the way you're using to get the Google Sheet is correct, but assuming that to be correct.

Try `print(resp.content)` instead of `print(resp)`, and checking the response manually, sometimes the server will return an error but still give response code 200.

Moreover, `resp.content` will return the bytes and you'll have to encode them into unicode yourself.

So try:

```
with open('C:\\AAA\\exportdata.xls', "wb", encoding="utf-8") as o:
    o.write(str(resp.content)[2:-1])
```

Comment: Google doc link is valid one. When I acccess it through browser it works fine. Tried following:
* `print(resp.content)`
prints the byte response, however it doesn't seem to have actual response.

* **Command:**
```
with open('C:\\AAA\\exportdata.xls', "wb", encoding="utf-8") as o:
```

**Gives Error:**
`ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`

When I open file in non-binary mode using
```
with open('C:\\AAA\\exportdata.xls', "w", encoding="utf-8") as o:
```
Google login page is shown in the excel sheet instead of actual contents. Any idea what could be wrong?