# R googlesheets4 range_speedread() cut the Sheets API out

Tags: r, google-sheets, httr

So following this [Github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues/302#issuecomment-1791490167) I hereby post this question:

The Google Sheets API has a max call rate of 300/min. When exceeding this you get a 429 error.

According to the github issue, it my be possible to remove the API call from `range_speedread()` altogether by just calling the csv file directly as [propsed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713084/download-link-for-google-spreadsheets-csv-export-with-multiple-sheets/64778214#64778214) with a http call

So the piece of code in `range_speedread()` which this does is (I guess):

```
library(googlesheets4)
library(readr)
# service account token
drive_auth(path =  .....json"))

#googlesheets4 authentication
gs4_auth(token = drive_token())

url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CTgM1g_aYoWFFpHU6A_qyqWGH0ulCFhs67uAcRVf1Rw/export?format=csv&gid=0"

token <- gs4_token()
response <- httr::GET(url, config = token)
df <- readr::read_csv(httr::content(response, type = "raw"))
```

First of all: does this really cuts out the API call? I tested it and I think it did cause I didnt see an increase in API call rate......however when I executed the code really quickly after each other, I still get a 429 error....why?